# Android Studio 3.2.1: mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes when connect firebase

Tags: android, firebase, gradle, connect

This is error *** All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found versions 28.0.0, 26.1.0. Examples include com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:28.0.0 and com.android.support:support-media-compat:26.1.0 less... (Ctrl+F1) 
There are some combinations of libraries, or tools and libraries, that are incompatible, or can lead to bugs. One such incompatibility is compiling with a version of the Android support libraries that is not the latest version (or in particular, a version lower than your targetSdkVersion).

this is error line on gradle dependancy =
 `implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'`

this is my gradle (app)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X2igR.png)

```html
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.thiyo.sdddddddddddddddddddd"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Please add the content of your build.gradle file and the entire error message.

Comment: um new to stack have mention error

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found answer thanks all helpers :-)

to resolve  i just added these line  gradle dependencies  block

like this

>

```
implementation 'com.android.support:customtabs:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
```

Answer (score 2):

add the following code to gradlebuild project not gradle app and it will solve your problem add it at the end .

```
subprojects {
    project.configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { details ->
            if (details.requested.group == 'com.android.support'
                    && !details.requested.name.contains('multidex') ) {
                details.useVersion "26.1.0"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: A little explanation in the answer will help others to understand the exact solution

Comment: this code will use a previous implementation dependency that will not mix the libraries if the current version makes the error

Answer (score 0):

Try This from Menu `File-> Invalidate Caches and Restart -> Invalidate and Restart`

If this doesn't work, delete `.idea` file(from root directory of project), `Build -> Clean Project` then `Build -> Rebuild Project`

Answer (score 0):

Try using both appcompat & support and then add other implementations

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
```